# Removing hash from URL using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I have the following code:

```
if(window.location.hash){
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
}
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
if(hash.length > 0 && hash.search('^y([0-9]+)g([0-9]+)$') >= 0)
{
    $('#recs').removeClass('closed');
    $('#rec_select_year').val(hash.match('y([0-9]+)')[1]);
    $('#rec_g_select').val(hash.match('g([0-9]+)')[1]);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#docs').offset().top + 200
    }, 0);
    changeDocuments();
}
else
{
    changeDocuments();
}
$('.filter').change(function() {
    updateDocumentList();
    var years = $('#rec_select_year').val();
    var groups = $('#rec_g_select').val();
    hash = 'y' + years + 'g' + groups;
});
```

I'm having difficulties with removing hash from URL. I need to change url to this http://codify.org/group/y2018g7

For that reason, I used substring() method to remove the hash, however it affects to the url and it changes to http://codify.org/group/, which basically removes the end of URL ../**y2018g7**

How can I change hash to to display an URL which is http://codify.org/group/y2018g7 ?

Comment: There's no hash part in either of your example URLs.

Comment: can you please tell what is the original URL you want to change?

Comment: @McRist the original URL was http://codify.org/group/#y2018g7. And I tried to changed this to the http://codify.org/group/y2018g7. However, I can't do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RegExp` to replace `#` from `url` like below.

```js
var url =  "codify.org/group/#y2018g7";
var regx = "/#/g";
var newUrl= url.replace(eval(regx), '');
console.log(newUrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Note: In above RegExp The g modifier is for global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match)*

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you want to replace all the hash with an empty string.

`window.location.href.split("#").join('')`